# progressbar for webbrowser control in wpf c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a wpf application with a tab which shows the WebBrowser control which loads the orders page of a given customer. This page has several calls for document and frames after which the control renders the content in the UI properly.

We are planning to implement a progressbar indicator for this tab and we used a progressbar with background worker.

We are setting the progressbar show property to true on the BrowserNavigating() event and show property to false upon DocumentComplete() of Browser control.
Since I am doing this the progressbar wont be shown in the UI continuously until all the http calls are completed successfully.so it goes on and off and which eventually gives a bad user experience.

When we are trying to load the orders page it makes at least 6-10 http calls to the server. So can we wait for all the calls to complete and only then hide the progress bar ? How do I keep track of these async calls ?

I am thinking we can use some kind of datastructure(e.g. Circular LL) to store all the calls (of BrowserNavigating and DocumentComplete) went but how do I know if all the calls are fired or not  before I wait for DocumentCompelte event?

Answer (score 1):

I don't how you could properly fix this, but maybe you can put a delay on the hiding of the progress bar by using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);` and replacing x with an amount of milliseconds. That way it will not hide for some time while the next http call can occur. After all calls have been made it will stay shown for that amount of time, but not forever.